# Symfony 5.4 translate form constraint message with limit

Tags: php, symfony

I want translate the constraints errors messages but I get the following error

> Invalid message format (error #65799): pattern syntax error (parse error at offset 27, after "oit comporter {", before or at "{limit}} caract"): U_PATTERN_SYNTAX_ERROR

here is the code

```php
<?php

$builder->add('company', TextType::class, [
    'label' => $this->translator->trans('company'),
    'constraints' => [
      new Length([
        'min' => 2,
        'minMessage' => $this->translator->trans('company.minlenght.error')
        /* below works */
        /*'minMessage' => "Le groupe doit comporter {{ limit }} caractères ou plus."*/
      ]),
      new NotBlank()
    ]
  ])
```

messages+intl-icu.yaml

```yaml
company.minlenght.error: Le groupe doit comporter {{ limit }} caractères ou plus.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use messageFormatter https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.messageformatter.php

```
$this->translator->trans('company.minlenght.error',['limit' => {{ limit }}])
```

messages+intl-icu.yaml

```
# translations/messages+intl-icu.en.yaml
company.minlenght.error: 'Le groupe doit comporter { limit } caractères ou plus.!'
```

Comment: Not passing limit as parameter worked since symfony use polyfill for intl. Using native intl require to pass the value for limit. Also see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/36753

Comment: Add quotes around '{{ limit }}': $this->translator->trans('company.minlenght.error',['limit' => '{{ limit }}'])